# reversing a number using do-while

Tags: java

**Create a java program that reads an integer number (NUM) and determine its reverse by using the division and remainder/modulo operators. If the last digit is zero, replace it with a one(1) before reversing the number. Output also the sum of all the digits.**

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static int replace(int number){
        if (number == 0)
            return 0;
        int digit = number % 10;

        if (digit == 0)
            digit = 1;

        return (number/10) * 10 + digit;
    }

    static int Convert(int number){
        if (number == 0)
            return 0;
        else
        return replace(number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number : ");
        number = kb.nextInt();
        System.out.println("replace:"+replace(number));
        int a, m = 0, sum = 0;

        do{
            a = replace(number) % 10;
            m = m * 10 + a;
            sum = sum + a;
            number = replace(number) / 10;
        }
        while( replace(number) > 0);

        System.out.println("Reverse:"+m);
        System.out.println("Sum of digits:"+sum);
    }
}
```

Currently the problem occurs in reversing the number because it also replace the last digit of the number, this should not happen.

> Input/Output of current program
>
> Enter the number : 2300
>
> replace:2301
>
> Reverse:1132
>
> Sum of digits:7

Comment: *FYI:* You should consider starting using spaces (4) or tabs to format your code. This will improve readability and maintainability of your code.

Comment: Another comment: You should start avoiding naming your class Main everytime, give it a meaningful name for what the program is doing: NumberUtility, NumberFlipper, whatever. Also, try to stop creating all of your methods as static. Instead, in you main method create a new instance of your class and call non-static methods: new NumberUtility().replace(). Finally, methods should not start with uppercase - they should be camel-case.

Comment: In your problem statement you say: 'If the last digit is zero, replace it with a one(1) before reversing the number. ' You have no code that does this check/update before calling reverse()

Comment: Your last edit to the question removed the explanation of what you were trying to do. Please bring it back to make the question more understandable to anybody who finds this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do this instead

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    static int replace(int number){
        if (number %10 == 0)
            return number += 1;
        return number;
    }

    static int Convert(int number){
        if (number == 0)
            return 0;
        else
            return replace(number);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int number;
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter the number : ");
        number = kb.nextInt();
        int a = 0, m = 0, sum = 0;

        number = replace(number);
        System.out.println("replace:" + number);

        do{
            a = number %  10;
            m = m * 10 + a;
            sum = sum + a;
            number /= 10;
        }
        while( number > 0);

        System.out.println("Reverse:"+m);
        System.out.println("Sum of digits:"+sum);
    }
}
```

Your code is fundamentally wrong because of the way you are replacing your numbers.

Changes made:

1. Changed replacing algorithm (You cannot change all 0 values to 1 that is wrong and why you got the wrong values)
2. Replace the number before you enter the loop. (You don't need to replace every iteration of the loop at 3 different place)

Expected output:

[image: output]

Comment: [**Please do not upload images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] your answer, pasting all text into the answer with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).